# SQL Server 2008 R2 Express cant connect to my editors

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008r2-express

I'm using SQL Server 2008 R2 Express to edit my database. I can edit my database with query codes but there is a editor program which can help me to edit my database easily.

But when I'm trying to open this editor program, I get an error:

> No SQL Server or there is no connection

In my opinion SQL Server 2008 R2 can't connect with this program basically. This editor program has an `option.ini` and I can write my database name and local.

Those editors were working for old SQL Server versions. But my database is suitable for SQL Server 2008 R2 express.

Comment: This is an issue with whatever this editor is that you are using.

Comment: Maybe if you mention the name of the editor it would help. Why not use SQL Server Management Studio?